# syncfusion, context menu, allow multiple cell selections

Tags: c#, winforms, gridcontrol, syncfusion

I am using the syncfusion grid control for a windows forms application
I am trying to select multiple cells in a grid. and on right click, the selection should remain. But not able to get the selection to remain
Here's mycode

```
 private void theGrid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        theGrid.ListBoxSelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
        this.theGrid.AllowSelection = GridSelectionFlags.Any; 
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {

            theGrid.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
            contextMenuStrip1.Visible = true;

        }
        else
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Visible = false;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the following setting while loading the form or initializing other control-related settings, to retain the selections on right click.

```
this.theGrid.SelectCellsMouseButtonsMask = MouseButtons.Left;
```